# Unit Testing in iOS 5: Is there a way to remove STAssertTrue() lines from the editor temporarily?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, xcode4

I find writing hundreds of STAssertTrue lines inbetween my code hurts readability a lot. Is there a way to remove these lines temporarily from the editor window so I don't see them?

I don't think there is. But sometimes good features are hidden...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly, but if you change

```
code
STAssert...
STAssert...
STAssert...
more code
```

to:

```
code
{
    STAssert...
    STAssert...
    STAssert...
}
more code
```

You could collapse braced part to {...} by clicking on the disclosure triangle to the immediate left of the text editing area.